# RecyclerView : item position intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I succeeded to put `onClickListener` for the `recyclerView`,but my problem here is

**Every item in the `recyclerview` go to the same new activity!!!**

Could we solve it with item position or what??

I'm trying to send each `RecyclerView` (ITEM or cell) to a new `activity`. Say the first one is Food, send it to a food page, the next is health, send it to a health page... etc. I'm trying to change the activity.class it sends the user to for each different view from the activity main.

My Adapter class

```
import java.util.List;

    public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.myViewHolder>{



        Context mcontext;
        List<item> mData;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;







        public Adapter(Context mcontext, List<item> mData) {
            this.mcontext = mcontext;
            this.mData = mData;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
            View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item,parent,false);

            return new myViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            holder.background_img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).background);
            holder.tv_title.setText(mData.get(position).profilename);
            holder.profile_photo.setImageResource(mData.get(position).profilephoto);
            holder.tv_subtitle.setText(mData.get(position).subtitle);
            holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    String shareBody = "Your body here";
                    String shareSub = "Your subject here";
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSub);
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                    mcontext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
                }
            });

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {




                    Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, SomaBay_bulding_Structure.class);

                    mcontext.startActivity(intent);


                }
            });

        }



        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            ImageView profile_photo,background_img;
            TextView tv_title,tv_subtitle;
            Button share;


            public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                profile_photo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_img);
                background_img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_background);
                tv_title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
                tv_subtitle=itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_subtitle);
                 share = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_share);


            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: You can check this answer it's have the same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53802272/7055487

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question: you need to start  activities depends on different item type, if you have this param:

```
            Intent intent;
            if(mData.get(position).type.equals("FOOD")){
              intent =  new Intent(mcontext, FoodActivity.class);
            }else if(mData.get(position).type.equals("HEALTH")){
                intent = new Intent(mcontext, HealthActivity.class);
            }else if(...){
                //
            }
            startActivity(intent);
```